# libQt6Core.so.6: version `Qt_6.6' not found

Tags: python, linux, pyqt6

At first, I apologize if my English is bad.

I have a laptop with two OS installed, one is Windows 11 the other is Linux mint 21.2 cinnamon 64bit.

I have written a desktop app about a year ago with `pyqt5`. Recently, I tried to update and develop some features in it. So i tried using `pyqt6`. I forgot to mention I use `VSCODE`.

The program had some compatibility issues with `PYQT6`, but finally I managed to solve them in  Windows 11.  I wanted to execute the code in Linux mint. But I got an error:

```
ImportError: /home/yousef/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/lib/libQt6Core.so.6: version `Qt_6.6' not found (required by /home/yousef/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/QtCharts.abi3.so)
```

i asked chatgpt for help and it said you must install qt6
i tried many times using qt online installer but without success. aftre downloading about 600 MB or one time after downloading about 2.5 GB it gave an error that it cant download some files ( i think the source code files, dont remember).
then i tried offline installing using qt6 source code i have downloaded from QT site. after extracting
according to Chatgpt  i did :

```
./configure -opensource -confirm-license -release -static
-static-runtime -no-feature-relocatable -prefix /opt/qt-6.6.1
```

and after that:

```
 make -j4
```

but when it was about 84% an error came up. there was no space left as the source code folder was more than 50 GB so i had to stop the process using ctrl+z, deleting that folder
copying the qt-everywhere-src-6.6.1.tar.xz to another drive, extracting files and then :

```
./configure -opensource -confirm-license -release -static
-static-runtime -no-feature-relocatable -prefix /opt/qt-6.6.1
```

but now it gaves this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/cmake/clang/ClangTargets.cmake:750 (message):   The imported target "clangBasic" references the file

     "/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/libclangBasic.a"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/cmake/clang/ClangTargets.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):   /usr/lib/cmake/clang-14/ClangConfig.cmake:19 (include)   qttools/cmake/FindWrapLibClang.cmake:17 (find_package)   qtbase/cmake/QtFindPackageHelpers.cmake:156 (find_package)   qttools/configure.cmake:20 (qt_find_package)   qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:674 (include)   qttools/src/CMakeLists.txt:18 (qt_feature_evaluate_features)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/media/yousef/Programming/qt-everywhere-src-6.6.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/media/yousef/Programming/qt-everywhere-src-6.6.1/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:1040 (message):   CMake exited with code 1.
```

what should i do now??
sorry if it was too long but i thought maybe you need this informations

Comment: maybe you have to install it with `apt` instead of `pip`. Or maybe you have to install `C/C++` library `Qt6` (also with `apt`). I use `PyQt6` on `Linux Mint 21.2 Mate` and I didn't have to compile it. And probably I installed it using `pip`. When I use `apt search qt6 | grep '^i'` to check installed modules then I see I have installed `libqt6core6 - Qt 6 core module`

Comment: @furas. Do you mean installing qt6 ? I'm not installing qt6 npt by apt nor by pip. what is the command for instaling qt6 with apt ?

Comment: I checked `pip3 show pyqt6` and it shows that I have version `6.5.0`. Maybe version `6.6` is too fresh version and it has problems with installation.

Comment: @furas i dont think its the problem with pyqt6. as it works fine in windows. for me pyqt6 is 6.4.2

Comment: it is problem with `Qt6` on your Linux. It seems python module `PyQt6` is searching C/C++ library `Qt 6.6` but it can't find it. So it has conflict between two versions. you could try to install `pip install PyQt6==6.5.0`

Comment: so you have `PyQt 6.4.2` but it uses `libQt6Core.so.6:` which is looking for `6.6`. If you would have `libQt6Core.so.6` for `6.4.2` (ie. installed with `apt` then you could replace it in `PyQt` (using normal `cp`)

Comment: @furas: acording to ChatGPT a did run `qmake --version` and this is the output:
`QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.15.3 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
it seems stil my problem is how to install qt6 on my system

Comment: maybe better try to install `PyQt6==6.5.0` but first uninstall all `PyQt`.

Comment: @furas. still the same problem

Comment: did you remove old version? Maybe it would need to delete manually files from python folder. `/home/yousef/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/`. I can't help more - `PyQt6` works on my Linux using only `pip install PyQt6` and I didn't need to mess with downloading source code and compiling it. BTW: you compiled to `/opt/qt-6.6.1` so maybe you should also remove it (and eventually restart system to remove libraries from memory).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256370/discussion-between-yousef-and-furas).

Answer (score 1):

It seems there was a bug or something with online qt installer. Today I tried again via QT6 online installer and QT6 installed successfully. Now my app works.